# Hand writing in first half of thick notebook

Tags: handwriting

I have a question similar to [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10771/how-to-write-in-a-very-thick-notebook), with a subtle difference.

I've got quite a nice leather bound notebook. It's about 2 inches thick.

However, I find it very difficult to write on the left hand pages, because there's such a massive drop to the desk. Supporting them with my hand just leaves the whole thing a mess.

I've tried propping a calculator or something underneath it and that's better, but it's still not ideal, anyone got any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy sheets of [foamboard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cathedral-A3-Foam-Board-White/dp/B00BYT1KS2) or foam rubber for craft purposes which you could stack up to support the left side of the book. Using anything too hard underneath (e.g. a hardback book, calculator with a hard plastic case, or piece of wood) is likely to mark the leather cover of your notebook when you lean or press on it, at least if the book is larger than the object beneath. If you have multiple thin sheets of foam it is easy to adjust the height of each side of the book as you work your way through it. Foam is also lightweight and easy to transport, unlike a large block of wood or other solid object.

This was suggested by a very expensive product, the [Kaiser Book Holder](https://www.photopaper.co.uk/shop/Kaiser-Book-Holder-44-41-p478676133); it's designed for photographing/scanning/copying books when you want both sides to be level, and comes with foam inserts to support either side of the book. But I don't suppose you want to pay GBP 380 (USD 450) for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Find a book of about the same height and width as your notebook, but slightly thinner.  Hopefully you have one which can replace your calculator, supporting the front cover of your notebook and the first few pages on an approximately horizontal plane.  That should give you a stable workspace to work while writing on the back side of your pages.
When you get to the point that your accumulated writing filled pages are stacking up uncomfortably, replace your supporting book with a slightly thinner book.  By replacing the supporting book periodically as you work your way though your note book, you should be able to fill both sides of all of the pages.